# wpf combobox default value to textBlock

Tags: wpf, dynamic, combobox, default

I need to add a default value 'select' in the combobox.I cant add this value to the database.This location value is dynamic.It appears based upon the userrole. I tried different ways nothing worked.Please help.

```
<ComboBox Width="140" ItemsSource="{Binding SecurityContexts, Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveSecurityContext, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      ToolTip="Working Location">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The code behind is
SecurityContexts = new ObservableCollection(_currentUser.ApplicationSecurityContexts);

```
public interface IApplicationSecurityContext
{
    IRole Role { get; }
    string Location { get; }
    IEnumerable<string> Budgets { get; }

}

public IApplicationSecurityContext ActiveSecurityContext
    {
        get { return this._currentUser.ActiveSecurityContext; }
        set
        {
            if (this._currentUser.ActiveSecurityContext != value)
            {
                this._currentUser.ChangeActiveSecurityContext(value);

                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentUser");

                LoadData();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you are going actually:have a collection of SecurityContexts classes, that expose a "Location" property that should be displayed as combobox item. You just need instead to add one element right?

Comment: Sorry for typo. It is "doing" instead of "going" in my previous comment. However if you don't give us some clarifications it will be hard to give you an answer. Maybe also post the code, not only the xaml, especially what is "SecurityContexts" and what is made of.

Comment: Thank you please check the added code..the combobox will show location1,location5 etc based upon the role of user...I just need to add a default value 'select' in the combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal using [CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx)

you can do this. Define resource in your grid/usercontrol/combobox:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding Binding SecurityContexts, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type c:SecurityContexts}">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

then your combobox itemsource will be:

```
<ComboBox.ItemsSource>
   <CompositeCollection>
      <ComboBoxItem>
         <TextBlock Text="select"/>
      </ComboBoxItem>
      <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source= {StaticResource cvs}}"/>
   </CompositeCollection>
 </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
```

It should work. You need to define your datatemplate for your collection in the resource too, to define how your item will be displayed

Note that c in c:SecurityContexts is the path where you defined your custom object

Comment: Thank you so much Daniele.. i tried to implement the solution that you provided...I am having issue with <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type c:SecurityContexts}">  ....it says SecurityContexts doesnot exist...i am new to wpf...i think i am doing something wrong..

Comment: Maybe i wasn't enough clear. c: represent the path where your app can find SecurityContexts. So you have to define something like this in your UserControl: xmlns:c="clr-namespace:yourProject.YourClass".